Laravel notification message between users guard using pusher
I have an application with one admin and multi-users. There is a chat section between user-to-admin, user-to-user. I want to send notification of message to user page who is receive the chat using pusher driver (localhost)..
Controller Code
public function userChat(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name;
        }
        if (Auth::guard('web')->check()) {
            $user = Auth::user()->name;
        }

        $user_id = $request->get('user_id');
        $purpose = $request->get('purpose');

        if ($purpose == 'find-user') {
            $msg = Chat::where('from', $user)->where('to', $user_id)
                ->orWhere('from', $user_id)->Where('to', $user)
                ->get();
            // dd($msg);
            return response()->json($msg);
        } elseif ($purpose == 'admin-user') {
            $val = $request->get('val');
            $chat = Chat::create([
                'message' => $val,
                'from' => $user,
                'to' => $user_id
            ]);
            // Get Receiver MSG ID
            $idReceiver = User::where('name', '=', $user_id)->pluck('id')->first();

            $data =[
                'sender' => $user,
                'receiver' => $idReceiver,
            ];
            event(new ChatNotify($data));
            return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'idReceiver' => $idReceiver, 'msg' => $val]);
        }
    }    

Blade File (app\layouts)
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/8.2.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher(MY_KEY, {
    cluster: 'mt1',
    encrypted: false
    });
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/pusherNotifications.js')}}"></script>

pusherNotifications.js
var notificationsWrapper = $('footer#footer_layouts');

// Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
var channel = pusher.subscribe('chat-notify');
// Bind a function to a Event (the full Laravel class)
channel.bind('App\\Events\\ChatNotify', function (data) {
    alert('hi');
    var newNotificationHTML = `<div id="IdChatMSG" style="position:fixed; right:0px; bottom:0px; z-index:999; display:block; width:300px; height:100px; background-color:black; color:red;">
    New Message From ` + data.sender + `
    </div>`;
    notificationsWrapper.append(newNotificationHTML);
});   

ChatNotify Event
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ChatNotify implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $sender;
    public $receiver;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->sender = $data['sender'];
        $this->receiver = $data['receiver'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return 'chat-notify';
    }
}  

.env file
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher


PUSHER_APP_ID=1344521
PUSHER_APP_KEY=XXXXXXX
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=XXXXXXX
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1   

config\app file
 App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,

config\broadcasting file
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
     'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'useTLS' => true,
      ],
   ],   
In js file

$('#input-chat').on('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($('#input-chat').val() != '' && ($('#input-chat').val().trim().length != 0)) {

            var val = $('#input-chat').val();
            var user = $('select#user-chat').val();

            setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: config.routes.userChat,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { val: val, user_id: user, purpose: 'admin-user' },
                    success: function (result) {
                        var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
                        let trRow = "<tr class='d-flex'>" +
                            "<td class='col-8 text-break'><b style='color:blue;'>" + result.user + "</b> : " + result.msg + "</td>" +
                            "<td class='col-4'>" + date + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                        $('#tbody-userChat').append(trRow).slideDown('slow');
                        $('#tbody-userChat').scrollTop($('#tbody-userChat').height() * 1000000);
                        $('#tbody-userChat').css({ 'display': 'block', 'height': '250px', 'overflow-y': 'auto' });

                        $('#input-chat').val('');
                        $('#input-chat').focus();
                        const url = '/images/msg.mp3';
                        const audio = new Audio(url);
                        audio.play();
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(request.statusText + "[" + request.status + "]");
                        alert(request.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});


Please can anybody help me. I want to achieve this tasks and send notification message to receiver user page
This is my error:


401 error means unauthorized. Have you checked your pusher credentials? Try to clear cache using php artisan optimize:clear

i cleared cache multiple times, put i get the same error
